# Parse server php sdk Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'Bad Request'

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I run Parse server, and now want to connect to server by Parse php sdk, but getting error Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'Bad Request'

```
ParseClient::initialize( 'app_id', null, 'master_key');
ParseClient::setServerURL('http://server_ip:1337', 'parse');

$query = new ParseQuery("_User");
$query->equalTo("username", "Mushegh");
$results = $query->find();
echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.";
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OP - Just wanted to follow up and see if you still had this same issue? I've been seeing some weird issues like this on PHP 7.1.8(RHEL) but not PHP 7.1.7(OSX)